# Visual Studio (C++) IntelliSense with parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

If I have a vector toto, when I write **toto.s** , IntelliSense gives me **toto.size** but I would like **toto.size()**. How to force IntelliSense to give me parentheses?

Comment: You know that Intellisense can also be completed by pressing the opening bracket (instead of pressing Enter or Tab), so the only thing you still have to type is the closing bracket? I hate it if closing brackets are given automatically, like in the XML editor...

Comment: Yes but I still have to write the final parenthesis. I hate it when I don't get my parentheses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible using the visual studio's intellisense. However check out this very good third party tool which can do that: [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution compatible with the express edition.

Comment: Since it seems that's not possible with current IntelliSense technology (what a shame), you get the accpeted answer.

Comment: Was there any revaluation if this is possible with newer versions?

Comment: In Vs 2015, if you type the opening parenthesis, you get the closing one for free. That's what I call progress.